# Misleading DOS tagging

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I am new on the site and am still working on good ol' DOS boxes (the actual DOSBox and FreeDOS, mainly). What I found out by searching this tag is that many users mistake DOS for the command line on Windows ([cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) or [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell)) and sometimes they mean [shell-scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) or at best [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file) (there is also batch and shell scripting for other languages and shells).

So I wonder: Is there a simple way to recategorize most of the mistakenly [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) tagged questions instead of going one by one?

**EDIT 1**: Just see [how people at Super User handled the same issue](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4969/the-dos-tag-is-ambiguous).

**EDIT 2**: So, would it be possible to turn the [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) tag into [dos-systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos-systems) via a tag-synonym, so that we may move on to retagging the command-line/batch-file questions to [windows-console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-console)? (There is no need for the tag `[windows-command-line]`, as suggested in my previous edit; `[windows-console]` will do.) The final step would be "burn and blacklist" the misleading DOS tag.

Comment: _"So I wonder if there is a simple way to recategorize most of the mistakenly DOS tagged questions instead of going one by one."_ Oh boy. I'm afraid that's too late now.

Comment: What ever you do, don't only retag a post, fix everything there is to fix for the post if you can.

Comment: Can you link to both a good and a bad example?

Comment: @RadLexus I don't think that's going to be useful. I'm in the process of fixing wrongly tagged questions, so any wrong example is likely to be gone. Better search for the tag `[dos]` and see the samples of the long queue.

Comment: @erreka _"and see the samples of the long queue"_ That's too vague criteria.

Comment: My question is since DOS is an operating system, is the tag needed?  Are there really programming related questions that would require this tag?

Comment: Tags are only meant to find experts to answer your question.  [dos] is highly selective for anybody at least 50 years old, the kind of people you want to find that can still remember it.  A rather small subset of the SO user crowd, nothing ever wrong with selective tagging  Use Google to search.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, I'm asking something of this sort: wouldn't be more useful retagging all these questions as `[cmd]` or `[batch]` or something like that? @HansPassant, most of the newer crowd really mean `[cmd]` or `[powershell]` when they say `[dos]`. (Perhaps Microsoft is here again to blame.)

Comment: @erreka so you think that the [tag:dos] should be removed completely and all questions appropriately retagged?  If that is correct, then it is not at all clear from your questions what you want done.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I think there are still valid dos tagged questions, related to vintage programming for that OS (I've set [a link to an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350032/no-program-entry-pointand-i-have-start-and-end-start)), but they must be clearly separated from the questions about the command line interpreters and their shell/batch programming capabilities.

Comment: So I fear the best way to proceed (and to educate the public) is to flag this tag as unusable, move all its tagged questions into `cmd` or `powershell`, and refer users with new questions to the more precise tags instead.

Comment: Good luck re-tagging a large portion of 2000 questions.

Comment: As @rene hinted at, please make sure you clean up as much of the question as you can. Also, please pace your suggested edits; if you flood the review queue with single-tag changes, it annoys people who need to review them all.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I'll go ahead and cleanup some tags in batches: a bunch every day.

Comment: I wouldn't call Super User "a sister project". It's rather "another Stack Exchange site".

Comment: But what should I tag my [ProDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_ProDOS) and [TRSDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRSDOS) questions?

Comment: I think ProDOS and TRSDOS questions (if they arise) can have their own tags, just like other platforms. See the difference between tags `mips` and `assembly`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I think ProDOS and TRSDOS fit in the generic tag `[dos-systems]`.

Answer (score 9):

Fixing the [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) tag has no easy solution. First you'd have to decide whether it's a tag worth keeping and if so how it should be defined. Second you'd then need to go through all 2000 posts with the tag and retag them accordingly.

### Justification for Burnination

As you note, [SuperUser decided that the tag wasn't worth keeping](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4969/the-dos-tag-is-ambiguous), and in fact they went so far as to [blacklist the tag](https://meta.superuser.com/a/8703), something that rarely happens. So burninating the tag here may also be a good idea. The [policy on burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate) gives four different reasons for removing a tag:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Of these I think you can make a strong case for 3 and 4 applying to the [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) tag. For questions related to the MS-DOS operating system and it clones and emulation this tag is redundant. The [ms-dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos) tag covers any question using the MS-DOS programming interfaces, even if they're not actually provided by MS-DOS.

The big problem with the tag is number 4. It has multiple meanings and worse a commonly used meaning is considered incorrect. Specifically [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) is used to refer to:

- MS-DOS and related operating systems
- (incorrectly) the Windows command line or Windows console windows
- Denial of service attacks
- (in theory) operating systems with DOS in their name unrelated to MS-DOS (eg. Amiga DOS, TRSDOS)

If it were just the last two it probably wouldn't be worth burninating the tag, it would be better to just retag the relatively few denial of service posts. I'm not sure if the tag has actually ever been used to refer to an OS that's not related to MS-DOS.

The incorrect usage of the [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) combined with its redundancy I believe provide sufficient justification for following SuperUser's lead and burninating the tag here. The problem is that this would be no easy task. It's not just that there almost 2,000 posts to retag, figuring out how to retag them correctly requires a fair bit consideration and expertise.

### How to Retag

I've been lazily retagging questions that are inappropriately tagged with [msdos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdos) for a while now. As new questions with this tag get posted and old questions become active I edit and retag these questions as necessary. Unfortunately, it can be difficult tell whether a batch file question is MS-DOS or Windows related.

Based on my experience here are my recommendations for retagging [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) questions, regardless of whether the tag is being completely burninated or not:

#### Retagging MS-DOS and Related OS Questions

Questions that use MS-DOS programming interfaces (eg. `INT 21h`) or batch-file questions that are using the MS-DOS `COMMAND.COM` command interpreter should be retagged as [ms-dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos). If they're specific to a particular emulator (eg. [dosbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dosbox) or clone (eg. [freedos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freedos)) make sure that these tags included as well. Watch for questions that don't use MS-DOS programming interfaces at all. For example while a custom bootsector runs in 16-bit real-mode, it loads instead of MS-DOS so the tag doesn't apply.

#### Retagging Windows Command Prompt Questions

A lot of these questions are ambiguous. A question like "How do I read a line into a variable in a batch-file?" is equally valid for MS-DOS and Windows (and OS/2 for that matter) despite the fact they have much different answers. Unfortunately, posters rarely spell out in the question which OS they're using. Asking them is often fruitless, even for new posts they either don't respond or don't understand the question.

If any of the following are true about the question, or any comments made by the original poster, I retag them as a Windows question:

- it has the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag
- it mentions Windows or a version of Windows (eg. Vista)
- the question uses in an example any batch features or commands not supported by MS-DOS (eg. `set /p` or `findstr`)
- the question refers to software or technology that either doesn't run under MS-DOS (eg. Chrome) or is extremely unlikely to be used under MS-DOS either currently or historically (eg. a Web server).

Note that early versions of software like Excel and Word did run under MS-DOS so it's not as definitive an indication that the questioner isn't using MS-DOS as I would prefer.

I don't retag based on the answers despite the fact that often questions like these have answers that only work under Windows.  Even if the original poster accepts one of them, unless there's some supporting comment (eg. "It worked"), I don't find this sufficient proof of the questioner's intent.

If you're retagging with the goal of burninating the tag then you may be forced to choose between the MS-DOS and Windows tags. In that case the answers would make for a good tie-breaker for cases there's no good evidence of intent. Otherwise I would just leave these questions alone.

Windows batch-file file questions should be retaged with the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd) and [batch-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/batch-file). Avoid tags like [command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command), [command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line) or [command-prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-prompt). These tags are rarely useful as they refer to the tagged thing itself. In particular the later tag is for the string displayed as a prompt for a command. The tag for the Windows command prompt, the console application that provides an interactive command interpreter and executes batch files (called simply "Command Prompt" by Windows), is [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cmd).

#### Retagging Windows Console Questions

Questions related to Windows' console windows and console applications sometimes are inappropriately tagged. These kinds of questions, ones that aren't batch related and involve code written in other languages like C# or Python, are almost always unambiguously Windows related. Most of these questions should be retagged with [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [console-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/console-application).

#### Dealing with Other Kinds of Questions

Questions about denial of service attacks should be retagged with [denial-of-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/denial-of-service). Questions about DOS operating systems unrelated to MS-DOS should be retagged with a tag specific to the OS.

You'll also discover a number of questions that are off-topic for one reason or an other. This includes a fair number of "DOS" questions that aren't programming related. If you have the privilege vote to close these questions.

#### Editing

Finally if you determine that the question isn't about MS-DOS or a related OS and retag it accordingly, you should also edit out any mention of DOS or MS-DOS in the question. You should also do any other editing necessary to bring the post up to standard (fix grammar, formatting, remove fluff, etc...), but it particularly important to replace these words so they don't encourage further misuse of the tag.

Comment: Since I don't have enough editing rights to go ahead and try to fix all the tags without disrupting the normal work of this community, I'd ask the community itself (people with enough editing rights, who are interested in following this process) to give a hand. Any idea how to coordinate this project?

Comment: @erreka There's a procedure to follow if you want to burniniate the tag, but currently it doesn't seem to be followed. If you just want to retag the questions that aren't about MS-DOS you could try posting a wiki answer here trying to coordinate the process, but this isn't something you should participate in unless you have full editing rights. For what it's worth I've started lazily retagging [dos] posts similar to how I lazily retag [msdos] posts.