# Is it appropriate to tag all questions relating to x86 real-mode assembly with dos or ms-dos?

Tags: discussion, tags

It is true that if you're working with x86_16 or x86 real mode in general, you are probably using some flavor of DOS, be it MS-DOS, FreeDOS, etc.  A lot of questions about real-mode assembly programming include either [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) or [ms-dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-dos).

However, if the question does not *specifically relate to* DOS or MS-DOS, is it still appropriate to include one of those tags? I often edit tags such as [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) out of programming questions if the question doesn't specifically relate to Windows, or [visual-c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-c%2b%2b), for example, if a question is about the C or C++ language but not the IDE itself - the fact that they are using that system is not really relevant to the question.

Should I apply the same logic to questions about 16-bit assembly?

Comment: I would say no. It is only applicable if the question or code uses the DOS API or can only be observed on DOS system.

Comment: It is a pretty decent contextual tag.  Most of these questions are asked with the [assembly] tag, it isn't specific enough to narrow down to this antiquated kind of programming.  [real-mode] could be an alternative, but it is very small.

Comment: Same question, different tags http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342436/792066

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**No.**

If the question is not actually about DOS programming or the DOS APIs, then it should *not* use the [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos) tag.

*All* questions about real-mode x86 programming should use the [x86-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-16) tag.

Arguably, any question with the [x86-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-16) tag should *also* use the [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) tag. (At least, this is my opinion. Even though it's 16-bit real mode, it's still x86 programming, and so should still have that "master" tag.)

---

Basically, if you're doing x86 programming, you want the [x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86) tag.

- If you're doing real-mode 16-bit programming, you also want the [x86-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-16) tag.
- If you're doing long-mode 64-bit programming, you also want the [x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x86-64) tag.

Then, you should add a language tag (*e.g.*, [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly), etc.).
If it's [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly), then:

- Also tag with the actual assembler that you are using (*e.g.*, [masm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/masm), [nasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nasm), [tasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tasm), etc.).
- If your question is specifically about AT&T syntax, you should consider adding the [att](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/att) tag.

Then, you should add an "environment" tag—for example, [dos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dos), [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows), [emu8086](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emu8086), [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux), etc. Or maybe you are building a boot loader and aren't operating in the context of any OS (this is a very popular type of question, for some reason). In that case, you would use the [bootloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootloader) tag.

Comment: This is absolutely perfect.

Comment: Q: However, if the question does not specifically relate to DOS or MS-DOS, is it still appropriate to include one of those tags? A: No. ... Then, you should add an "environment" tag—for example, dos. R: Maybe I misread this, but isn't this just the yes to the no?

Comment: @sebastian It doesn't seem unclear to me. If the question does not specifically relate to DOS, then you don't use the DOS tag. If it *does* (i.e., your "environment" is DOS), then you use the DOS tag. The point is, just because you're doing 16-bit real-mode programming doesn't necessarily imply that you are using DOS. DOS happens to be a 16-bit real-mode operating system, but it certainly isn't the only one, and you might not even *be* using an OS (as in the example I give, where you're writing a boot loader).

Comment: @CodyGray When I read that block, I read: specifically related as in not my environment but actually DOS-API or DOS functions. The text says he often edits posts about C/C++ with windows-tag (as your mentioned environment), but removes windows tag, since the question is not about windows/MS-*: the fact that they are using that system is not really relevant to the question. Maybe the intention of the author is not totally clear, whereas I support your explanation of how to tag.

Comment: I don't think I understand your comment, @sebastian. I guess the word "environment" is confusing? Obviously don't add tags that are irrelevant to your question just because you happen to be running a particular operating system. If you are asking about a C++ standard library feature, it doesn't matter if you're running Windows and you shouldn't include that tag. Same thing if you're asking about the most efficient way to clear a register in x86. You don't need to include the [dos] tag just because you're running DOS. You only use it if the question is *about* DOS programming.

Comment: TL;dr: use the tags that are relevant to the question.

Comment: It was actually suggested previously that we blacklist the [dos] tag, just like Super User has done, because its so badly misused. Mostly because the endless Windows batch-file questions but also the occasional denial-of-service question. That would mean retagging DOS operating system questions with the less abused [ms-dos] instead of the other way around. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320573

Comment: Thanks for the note, @Ross. I had somehow missed that discussion. Definitely something to consider.